# memcached entry expiration set to 0

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

Does memcached entries with expiry time set to 0 not expire - as mentioned in the [PHP Memcached docs](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php), but not mentioned in the [memcached protocol spec](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L79)?

I am using spymemcached client and the docs for spymemcached does not say anything about it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting expiration to 0 means the item has no expiration. Therefore it will never expire.

Comment: Can you substantiate it? As I mentioned, I do not see it in the memcached protocol spec.

Comment: @tbaker [the memcached wiki on github](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Programming#expiration) explicitly says: _'Expiration times are specified in unsigned integer seconds. They can be set from 0, meaning "never expire", to 30 days'_