# What means that expiration time in Memcached client is set to zero?

Tags: java, memcached

I am looking at the legacy code and see the call to the MemcachedClient

```
public boolean set(final String key, final int exp, final Object value)
        throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, MemcachedException;
```

exp (expiration time) is set as 0 but in the comments I see that it results in 30 days expiration  time.  According to [memcached entry expiration set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212647/memcached-entry-expiration-set-to-0) that means no expiration at all.
What expiration time can I expect?

Comment: Key expiration time you specify while starting memcache server, this is set method and I guess it should throw timeoutException after opTimeout is expired. Optimeout you specify while create cache writer object. You should also specify which library you are using like spymemcache